# How to deal with different time series of variable length with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, data-science

I have data matrix in which each row considered as time series but of different length. This is how it looks like:

[image: This is how it looks like]

In text:

> 0 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>
> 0 12  32  45  67  89  54  23.0    56.0    78.0    98.0
>
> 1 34  76  34  89  34  3   NaN NaN NaN NaN
>
> 2 76  34  54  12  43  78  56.0    NaN NaN NaN
>
> 3 76  56  45  23  43  45  67.0    76.0    67.0    8.0
>
> 4 87  9   9   0   89  90  6.0 89.0    NaN NaN
>
> 5 23  90  90  32  23  34  56.0    9.0 56.0    87.0
>
> 6 23  56  34  3   5   8   7.0 6.0 98.0    NaN
>
> 7 32  23  34  6   65  78  67.0    87.0    89.0    87.0
>
> 8 12  23  34  32  43  67  45.0    NaN NaN NaN
>
> 9 343 76  56  7   8   9   4.0 5.0 8.0 68.0

I had tried reading data using pandas with code:

```
timeseries=pd.read_excel('timeseries.xlsx',header=None)
######   timeseries   ##############
print(timeseries)
```

Then I want to pass each row of datamatrix to timeseries analysis model which will generate a single value for each timeseries and after passing all timeseries I'll get a feature vector.

I had tried implementing using code below:

```
features=[]
for i,j in timeseries.iterrows():
    row=timeseries.iloc[i]
    model=AR(row.values)
    model_fit=model.fit()
    yhat=model_fit.predict(len(row),len(row))
    features.append(yhat)
fvector=pd.DataFrame(features)
print(fvector)
```

but I got this as error

> MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans

To the best of my knowledge it occurs as the analysis method restricts NaN value and throws this error but according to my situation each time series needs to be considered as independent input to the analysis method and should read till the last real value of each row.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please don't post images of your data, share the actual data which can be copied.

Comment: Done, Thanks for the suggestion .

Comment: Fill missing values before applying the model. Many of time-series models doesn't work with missing values like NaNs.

Comment: no i can't interpolate or impute the data in anyway...is it possible that i parse each row independently so that NaN does not be marked by pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the NaNs and replace them with 0 or something else:

```
timeseries.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(timeseries)
features=[]
for i,j in timeseries.iterrows():
    row=timeseries.iloc[i]
    model=AR(row.values)
    model_fit=model.fit()
    yhat=model_fit.predict(len(row),len(row))
    features.append(yhat)
fvector=pd.DataFrame(features)
print(fvector)

            0
0  100.704274
1    0.000000
2    0.000000
3  -23.468840
4   19.943124
5   37.442981
6    5.771667
7  105.138431
8    0.000000
9  237.903666
```

Comment: can't replace NaN with any value. Is it possible that i read the values of each row till NaN occurs in it?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't present all needed details, e.g. you wrote
nothing about *AR*.

As I understood, your software complains about *NaN* values in some rows,
so you should:

- eliminate *NaN* values from each row,
- only **after** that process it.

Another detail, this time concerning the execution speed, is that if you iterate over rows then:

- the second control value of the loop already contains the current row,
- thus there is no point in reading it again by index.

So change your code do something like below:

```
for i, row in timeseries.iterrows():
    row = row.dropna()
    print(f'{i}: {row.size:2}  {row.values}')
    # Any further processing of "row"
```

Of course, *print* is only for demonstration purpose.
Drop it in the target version of your code.

I doubt whether replacement of *NaN* values with zeroes (as proposed
in the other answer) is the right approach, as it is likely to "spoil"
something in your model.

## Edit

If you want to process only the "initial" part of the current row, i.e.
up to the first *Nan* (excluding), as you asked in your comment,
replace the call to *dropna()* with:

```
row = row[row.isna().cumsum() == 0]
```

To check how it works, replace e.g. the last *NaN* in row with index
*1* with some finite value and observe the result for this row.

Comment: Is it possible that i read the values of each row till NaN occurs in it? and if yes then what will be the approach to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy and enter the missing values as `np.NaN`.
Then you can read the data as a NumPy array, transpose it (because in pandas a time series is supposed to be a column rather than a row), cast it to a DataFrame, set a DatetimeIndex and take it from there.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.asarray([[12, 32, 45, 67, 89, 54, 23.0, 56.0, 78.0, 98.0],
                   [34, 76, 34, 89, 34, 3, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   [76, 34, 54, 12, 43, 78, 56.0, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   [76, 56, 45, 23, 43, 45, 67.0, 76.0, 67.0, 8.0],
                   [87, 9, 9, 0, 89, 90, 6.0, 89.0, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   [23, 90, 90, 32, 23, 34, 56.0, 9.0, 56.0, 87.0],
                   [23, 56, 34, 3, 5, 8, 7.0, 6.0, 98.0, np.NaN],
                   [32, 23, 34, 6, 65, 78, 67.0, 87.0, 89.0, 87.0],
                   [12, 23, 34, 32, 43, 67, 45.0, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   [343, 76, 56, 7, 8, 9, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 68.0]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data.T)
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range('2020-05-15', periods=10, freq='d'))

df
```

```py
               0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8        9
2020-05-15  12.0    34.0    76.0    76.0    87.0    23.0    23.0    32.0    12.0    343.0
2020-05-16  32.0    76.0    34.0    56.0    9.0     90.0    56.0    23.0    23.0    76.0
2020-05-17  45.0    34.0    54.0    45.0    9.0     90.0    34.0    34.0    34.0    56.0
2020-05-18  67.0    89.0    12.0    23.0    0.0     32.0    3.0     6.0     32.0    7.0
2020-05-19  89.0    34.0    43.0    43.0    89.0    23.0    5.0     65.0    43.0    8.0
2020-05-20  54.0    3.0     78.0    45.0    90.0    34.0    8.0     78.0    67.0    9.0
2020-05-21  23.0    NaN     56.0    67.0    6.0     56.0    7.0     67.0    45.0    4.0
2020-05-22  56.0    NaN     NaN     76.0    89.0    9.0     6.0     87.0    NaN     5.0
2020-05-23  78.0    NaN     NaN     67.0    NaN     56.0    98.0    89.0    NaN     8.0
2020-05-24  98.0    NaN     NaN     8.0     NaN     87.0    NaN     87.0    NaN     68.0
```

For details, see the [pandas Time Series documentation.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)

If the model function really does not accept any missing values, you may have to guess them in some way. This will of course affect the model reliability. See the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html), in particular on [df.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna), and the [Wikipedia article on Imputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)).

You can also extract a single time series without the missing values from the above data frame, in case that is suitable for your model. E.g. the second column:

```py
df[1].dropna()
```

```py
2020-05-15    34.0
2020-05-16    76.0
2020-05-17    34.0
2020-05-18    89.0
2020-05-19    34.0
2020-05-20     3.0
Freq: D, Name: 1, dtype: float64
```